# Fastest way to calculate Disk usage for Larger directories in GB's

Tags: disk-usage

I have directories which are in GB's in linux file system. I want disk usage the fastest way to get the directories list.  how much disk space is consuming for each directory. I used du in background but it takes lot of time (probably days to find each directory usage).

Answer (score 1):

You can try tree:

```
tree -d -h --du
```

-d only print directories, 
-du disk usage, 
-h human friendly output

Comment: Is this command get the fastest way of disk usage for each directory ? I dont need subdirectories size. Just need parent directory

Comment: To be honest I've always used `du`, tree is another option I don't know comparative speed: `du --max-depth 1 -h`

Comment: Any other tool/command line options to get bigger disk usage of directory. bcoz my data in each directory is consuming more than 50 GB it takes time to get i guess.. If i can get very fast using alternative tool/commands i hope that would be better